# Essential NuGet packages broken in MVC 6 (Asp.net 5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, nuget, nuget-package

I have started a new project in MVC 6 and a lot of the essential packages are not working, e.g. EntityFramework and WindowsAzure.Storage.

After I install from NuGet I get:

> NU1002 The dependency WindowsAzure.Storage 6.2.0 in project App does not support framework DNXCore, Version=5.0.

Is their any way to fix this, or are the packages just out of date and I should stick with MVC 5?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WindowsAzure.Storage 6.2.0 does not support ASP.NET Core projects.

Try the latest pre-release version instead [WindowsAzure.Storage 6.2.2-preview](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/6.2.2-preview). This NuGet package has been updated to support ASP.NET Core projects - it contains a lib\dotnet directory as well as a PCL and also defines dependencies for the .NETPlatform, which the 6.2.0 version does not.

Comment: Surprisingly latest stable version 7.0.0 even does not support.

Comment: 7.2.0 does not support either.